# These top tags are thinking out of box

Tags: bug, tags, design

I just saw this [user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7602822/dheeraj-tripathi) profile who has top tags of [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) and [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation).

[image]

Those scores and posts content are going out of the container.

Comment: I want to burninate something now because of that pun in the title.

Comment: This is what it looks like on Windows 7, 32-bit, IE 11.0.9600.18860 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdrBR.png

Comment: But I made the round mark better than the one in the exact dupe.

Comment: @Justastudent tbh, I asked this question only because these title came into my mind :p